# XSL Using Params in a contains function

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Is it possible to use params as the data for a contains function?

I have a C# file that is passing information to a XSL sheet in the form of param's to make a html page that prints out the data. If I hard code the information it works but if i use params instead it returns nothing yet if i print out the information using a text tag it works so i know the value being passed in should be correct.

```
<xsl:param name="type"/>
<xsl:param name="filter"/>

<xsl:for-each select="london-schools/school [contains($type, '$filter')]">
```

that is what I am trying to do, and it just returns the table headings instead of information.

Thanks, Brandon.

Comment: To clarify Type is the name of the node (Either fullname or type) and filter is a word they are looking for.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant:

```
<xsl:for-each select="london-schools/school [contains(type, $filter)]">
```

It's hard to tell for sure without seeing your input and the expected output - but certainly, if `type` is the name of a node, then it should not be prefixed by `$`, and if `$filter` is a parameter, then it should not be quoted.

Note also that XML is case-sensitive; you mention both `type` and `Type` - they are not the same.

---

### Added:

I'm really guessing here, but consider the following:

**XML**

```
<records>
    <record>
        <name>Alpha</name>
        <type>Bravo</type>
    </record>
    <record>
        <name>Bravo</name>
        <type>Bravo</type>
    </record>
    <record>
        <name>Charlie</name>
        <type>Alpha</type>
    </record>
    <record>
        <name>Delta</name>
        <type>Alpha</type>
    </record>
</records>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="property"/>
<xsl:param name="value"/>

<xsl:template match="/records">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="record[contains(*[name()=$property], $value)]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above stylesheet is applied to the input with parameters:

```
$property = "name"
$value = "Bravo"
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
  <record>
    <name>Bravo</name>
    <type>Bravo</type>
  </record>
</records>
```

When the parameters are:

```
$property = "type"
$value = "Bravo"
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
  <record>
        <name>Alpha</name>
        <type>Bravo</type>
    </record>
  <record>
        <name>Bravo</name>
        <type>Bravo</type>
    </record>
</records>
```

Comment: type is a param so the $ is need yes. I removed the ' ' from $filter and that helped so ty. 

Now it works with the $filter and the hard coded type but not with the $type as a parameter. Is it even possible to do?

Comment: If type is a parameter, then your predicate makes no sense, because it will return the same value for every school. I have added a guess as to what you really want to do here. If that doesn't solve your issue,  please edit your question and add an example of the input and the expected output.